# vscode show the wrong type inference error when using typescript, how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

In my .ts file, I have some code like that:

```
    **// at first, the store only can be *GlobalStore* type or *null* type.**
    **// now the vscode reference is right.**

    let store = inject(GLOBAL_PROVIDER_KEY, null)

    if (!store) {

        **// then, the store only can be *null* type.** 
        **// now the vscode reference is also right.**

        console.log(store);
        
        **// the `createDefaultStore` function return the `GlobalStore` type**
        **and equal to the store. But vscode inference is GlobalStore | null type!**
        **this is wrong.**

        store = createDefaultStore();

    }
```

It seems like the problem about [language-server](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide).

I don't know how to fix the vscode typescript reference or where to find the answer. It is a bug or the config is wrong? Now it report error with red wavy line.

Can I only use `store = createDefaultStore() as GlobalStore` to solve it?

Comment: I found that `store = createDefaultStore() as GlobalStore` still can't solve the problem

Comment: Please don't [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/74738785) and repost questions; there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/74738785/edit/) feature you can use.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I am using the edit feature.

Comment: Reposting isn't editing.

Comment: @Larnu sorry, I don't seem to understand what you mean. How should I operate now? When I asked the same question before, it was a mistake. Now I have posted it again, and the last question has been deleted.